# How to update MirrorMaker 2 topics whitelist?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I run MirrorMaker2 with the high-level driver, as documented [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0#KIP-382:MirrorMaker2.0-RunningadedicatedMirrorMakercluster), with `./bin/connect-mirror-maker.sh mm2.properties` running in 3 pods in a k8s deployment.

The mm2.properties file looks like this:

```
clusters = source, dest

source.bootstrap.servers = ***:9092
dest.bootstrap.servers =  ***:9092

source->dest.enabled = true
dest->source.enabled = false

source->dest.topics = event\.PROD\.some_id.*

replication.factor=3

checkpoints.topic.replication.factor=3
heartbeats.topic.replication.factor=3
offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor=3

offset.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.replication.factor=3
config.storage.replication.factor=3

sync.topic.acls.enabled = false
```

This works fine, with all topics matching the `event\.PROD\.some_id.*` regex being replicated.
Now, when I need to add other topic the whitelisting, I expected to be able to simply scale everything down, update the regex, and scale everything up again.

When I update the whitelist regex to `source->dest.topics = event\.PROD\.(some_id|another_id).*` , the topics matching `"another_id"` are created in the dest cluster, but no data is replicated, and mirrormaker seems to be lost commiting offsets:

```
[2020-05-28 20:33:19,496] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:424)
[2020-05-28 20:33:19,496] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:441)
[2020-05-28 20:33:19,499] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} Finished commitOffsets successfully in 3 ms (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:523)
```

Is this a limitation of the high level driver, or am I doing something wrong? From my understanding, being able to dynamically add topics to the whitelist was one of the motivations for MM2.

Answer (score 1):

I am playing with mmv2 as well. Can you try setting these configurations? I had to enable the `sync.topic.configs.enabled` parameter so my mmv2 would detect the new topics and their data.

```sh
refresh.topics.enabled = true
sync.topic.configs.enabled = true
refresh.topics.interval.seconds = 10
```

Pd.- I am adding my reply as an answer because I wanted to paste come configs.

Comment: According to the docs here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0#KIP382:MirrorMaker2.0-ConnectorConfigurationProperties, the first two are already true by default, and the refresh interval is 5 sec.

Comment: Yeah, I read the same thing. But didn't work. I thing I tried it with 2.4.0 which gave a lot of problems. With 2.5 I had no issues.